# Can I download the same Keyboard 1 voice from my Yamaha P45 to use as a midi voice on my DAW

Tags: midi

I am using Ardour as my DAW and I have a bunch of midi sounds in there, I use my Yamaha P45 as a midi controller to input the midi notes into my DAW.
However, I am currently using the Keyboard 1 voice from the P45, it has a lovely tone that changes when I hit the keys harder and gives me the sound I am looking for. But when I use my DAW to play back the midi I don't have that exact same voice. I could use Direct Audio in jack (which I tried) to get the voice from the keyboard, but I like the ability to tidy up my performance within the DAW.
So, it seems like a simple question, where can I download the Midi sound bank (if that is the right term) to match the Keyboard 1 voice on the P45 so I can play it back through my DAW to sound the same as my keyboard?

Any help Appreciated

Bezz

Answer (score 3):

You can't download it.  But you can use the P45's sounds in your Ardour projects by routing a MIDI track out to it.  Once the MIDI data is tweaked to your satisfaction, play the song with that track soloed while recording the P45's audio output to an audio track.

This isn't as complicated as it might sound!  A small audio mixer will be useful, but it can be done without one.

Answer (score 2):

I did not get if you tried that already:

In Ardour you can record a MIDI track and then ask Ardour to feed this track in one of your MIDI port linked to your keyboard instead of in one of Ardour's plugin.

Obviously, you'll need to feed the keyboard's output inside Ardour each time (in the main bus maybe?) but this way you'll get the simplicity of recording a MIDI file and the sound of your keyboard (which you can then properly record for the final rendering).

Actually, this is equivalent of using your keyboard as a plugin: feed in MIDI, get audio out ;).

If I remember well there also the possibility to do "mixed track" (midi + audio) in Ardour but I do not remember exactly how...

Not exactly an answer to your question, but maybe a starting point?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get that exact sound from anywhere except your keyboard. It is proprietary & will not have been made available anywhere outside of physical shipped products.

Your alternative is one of the many VST plugins that can make piano sounds - from free to hundreds of $£€

There are far too many to attempt to list, but such as ToonTrack do a very acceptable budget range, including grand & upright piano models - see https://www.toontrack.com/ezkeys-line/ or just google 'piano vst'.

Comment: Ah, that's a shame. My follow up question is then where/how do I find a plugin that sounds as close to the P45 Electric piano 1 voice as possible? I have plenty of plug ins for my DAW but this sound has a certain e.piano style to it that I'd like to use. I guess I have to do trial and error. Oh and thank you for the reply.

Comment: ToonTrack have several E.Piano models, but there's a very neat E.Piano 'simulator' called Lounge Lizard, which can do pretty much any EP sound, including ones that would be physically impossible. It's very very neat - https://www.applied-acoustics.com/lounge-lizard-ep-4/ It's actually far more subtle than the usual Yamaha EPs [unless they're upped the ante significantly since I left]